# Why WPF TextBox's Undo method doesn't work if the value is initialized in constructor?

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox, undo

I have written a simple WPF application in which I wanted to test the **Undo** method provided by WPF TextBox. Basically on clicking the Undo button the value of TextBox has to be reverted.

This is my xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="textBox1"  />
    <Button Name="button1" Click="button1_Click">Undo</Button>
    <Button Name="button2" Click="button2_Click">Change value to 100</Button>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In my xaml.cs, I have written the following:

**Case 1: Where Undo is working:: I click on "Change value to 100" button on the window, the TextBox's text becomes 100. Now I click on Undo button the value of TextBox becomes empty.**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Undo();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "100";
    }
}
```

**Case 2: Where Undo is not working:: I set the value of TextBox's text to 100 in constructor, the TextBox's text becomes 100. Now I click on Undo button the value of TextBox doesn't become empty !!**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = "100";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Undo();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**Why doesn't the Undo functionality work in second case? 
Is it because the TextBox is still not constructed ? But I checked all the properties of TextBox like Loaded, Initialized , etc which were all set to "True"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the technical reason, but many controls in WPF won't be fully functional until *after* the constructor. But you can still work around this by hooking the Loaded event.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //textBox1.Text = "100";
        textBox1.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(textBox1_Loaded);
    }

    void textBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "100";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Undo();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

The Undo button should work properly then.

Comment: It works. I will go ahead and select your answer. But I was trying more and finally found that textBox1.SelectedText = "100"; works !